# capistranoでyarnとか入れようとしたらエラーになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

設定を変更してproductionでyarnを使えるようにすると以下エラーが出ます
bundle exec cap production deploy

```
     01 yarn install --prefer-offline --production --no-progress
  01 Node version 0.10.46 is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or 
higher.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as         
ban@xxxxxxx: yarn exit status: 1
yarn stdout: Nothing written
yarn stderr: Node version 0.10.46 is not supported, please use 
Node.js 4.0 or higher.


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: yarn exit status: 1
yarn stdout: Nothing written
yarn stderr: Node version 0.10.46 is not supported, please use 
Node.js 4.0 or higher.

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => yarn:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as 
ban@xxxxxxxx: yarn exit status: 1
yarn stdout: Nothing written
yarn stderr: Node version 0.10.46 is not supported, please use Node.js 
4.0 or higher.


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 
lines:
```

awsなんでsshで直接入ってyarnをインストールしても同じエラーが出ます。
解決方法ご存知でしたら教えてください

環境は以下の通りです。

```
$ cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09

$ yum --version
3.4.3
Installed: rpm-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 at 2016-09-23 10:00
Built    : Amazon.com, Inc. <http://aws.amazon.com> at 2015-11-16 21:31
Committed: Ben Cressey <bcressey@amazon.com> at 2015-03-25

Installed: yum-3.4.3-137.67.amzn1.noarch at 2016-09-23 10:01
Built    : Amazon.com, Inc. <http://aws.amazon.com> at 2016-09-20 21:41
Committed: Andrew Jorgensen <ajorgens@amazon.com> at 2016-09-12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージをみたところものすごく古いnode.js(0.10.46)がインストールされているようです。

このバージョンでは使用できないので何らかの方法で新しいものに入れ換えてください。

Comment: >このバージョンでは使用できないので何らかの方法で新しいものに入れ換えてください。  すみません、そのなんらかの方法を教えていただきたく

Comment: 方法は色々ありますが、そもそも問題の発生している環境についての情報が少なすぎます。せめて「問題の発生している環境のOS・ディストリ等はなにか」(AWSということなのでAmazon Linuxでしょうか？それともそれ以外？)、「現在入っているnodeはどのように入れたものなのか」など

Comment: Amazon Linuxでyumで入れていてそうなるのであればこのあたりでしょうか……といっても10.46ということなので違うのかな…… https://qiita.com/moomooya/items/d8733277f32e4a851a71

Comment: sshでnvmにnodeを直接入れてv8にしました。sudoつけないでnode -vをすると8.0が出るのですが、sudoつけると0.10が出ちゃいます、、

Comment: ```
sudo which node
/usr/bin/node
```
ここのnodeを消すとcapistranoでnodeないエラーになりました、、